# 'Join' DocumentDB collections (NoSQL)

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I've got two collections, which are called `shop` and `product`.

`Shop` looks like:

```
{
  "id": "96-17",
  "occasion": {
    "pk": 17
  },
  "pk": 96,
  "title": "Ebay",
  "description": "Test Description",
  "phone": "+1111111111",
  "logo": {
    "name": "shop.png",
    "_links": {
      "thumbnail": "https://test.server.com/image.png"
    }
  }
}
```

`Product` looks like:

```
{
  "id": "35671-17",
  "occasion": {
    "pk": 17
  },
  "pk": 35671,
  "title": "Best tablet on earth.",
  "hero": {
    "name": "product.png",
    "_links": {
      "tile": "https://test.server.com/image.png"
    }
  "shop": {
    "pk": 96,
    "title": Ebay
   }
  }
}
```

How am I able to get a list of all products from the `Product` collection, and 'join' the `Shop` collection with the `product.shop.pk ON shop.id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot perform joins across collections. You'd need two queries - one for `Product` and one for `Shop`. Note: This is true even with stored procedures, which are scoped to a collection.

If you *must* perform such lookups with a single transaction, you can consider storing both types of data within a single collection to facilitate this.